# Проблема в Post запросе

Tags: c#, post

Хочу пройти авторизацию на сайте, но что то не получается.... подскажите что не так?

```
 public string send(string url, string par)
    {
        String secondStepForm3 = par;
        HttpWebRequest request3 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request3.UserAgent = "Opera/9.80";
        request3.Method = "POST";
        request3.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] EncodedPostParams3 = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(secondStepForm3);
        request3.ContentLength = EncodedPostParams3.Length;
        request3.GetRequestStream().Write(EncodedPostParams3, 0, EncodedPostParams3.Length);
        request3.GetRequestStream().Close();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request3.GetResponse();
        string lol = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
        return lol;
    }
```

Метод вызываю так

```
   string Auth = send("http://www.studymode.com/login.php","username=assemdos&password=qwerty");
```

Comment: все просто, пароль не тот

Comment: Пароль я ввожу тот, это для примера

Comment: А вы уверены в верном формате передачи данных? Лично я когда отправлял POST запросы использовал либо json, либо KeyValue. Правда я не пользовался HttpWebRequest. Я использовал WebClient или HttpClient. Они гораздо проще в использовании)

Comment: Какая ошибка-то???

Comment: У меня возвращается страница не авторизиров. пользователя

Comment: Проблема была в куках, сделал

Comment: Не сделал, куки были ошибочные))))

Comment: А вы уверены, что такой POST можно отправить? Что он валидный. Я перешёл по Вашей ссылке и руками его пробую отправить. Но, увы, он не уходит. Более того, когда я смотрю, какие запросы улетают при попытке авторизации, ничего близкого к тому, что Вы делаете, не формируется.

Comment: @hedgehogues Не подскажите где я допустил ошибку??? Вот тестовый логин\пароль
Aliscrap721@aol.com:faro1224

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что на данном сайте фронт обрабатывает пароли каким-то образом, после чего формируются хэши. И вот они-то уже и отправляются на серв.

Comment: @hedgehogues http://seriyps.ru/postget/ тут отправило без вопросов